# React Navigation passing data with function call on navigate

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to pass a variable (i can do this) and run a function with that variable as soon as navigation happened.

Function takes value of a input field. But because i assigned input field to my variable i'm having some trouble on render method because it overwrites the data after navigation or not even write it. It works when manually input but i need to pass this variable from camera also(this also works fine).

**Main Page**

```
  onChange(obj) {
    const value = obj;
    if (value) {
     this.setState({
      buttonDisabled: false,
      text: value,
     });
    } else {
     this.setState({
      buttonDisabled: true,
      text: ''
    });
   }
  };


render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const scanCode = navigation.getParam('text', '');

    return (
      <View style={{padding: 30, paddingTop: 40}}>
        <TextInput autoFocus
          ref='queryInput'
          style={{height: 40}}
          placeholder="placeholder.."
          value={scanCode === '' ? this.state.text : scanCode}
          onChangeText={this.onChange.bind(this)}
          onSubmitEditing={this.runQuery}
        />
        <Button
          onPress={this.runQuery}
          title="run"
          color="#841584"
          accessibilityLabel="query"
          disabled={this.state.buttonDisabled}
        />
      <Button title='Camera' style={{position: 'absolute', bottom: 0, left: 0}} onPress={() => this.gotoCamera()}></Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

**Camera Page**

```
gotoMainPage = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', {
            text: this.state.qrcode
        })
    }
    onBarCodeRead = (e) => this.setState({qrcode: e.data}, () => this.gotoMainPage());
```

is it possible to setState of a value in Main page from Camera Page or what should i do here?

Thanks

Comment: You're missing a function so I can't give you a code answer. `this.gotoCamera()`. Basically, you parse the current state so when you call `navigate('camera', { mainState: this }` then you can call `props.mainState.setState()` or access the state with `props.mainState.state`

Comment: what i want is when navigate('Home', { text: this.state.qrcode }) i want to replace this.state.text value with it on Home Page by setState otherwise it always replaces it on every render

Comment: When navigating to the Home page, you're re-rendering the component. If you're using like a stackNavigation, you can use `this.props.navigation.goBack()` to continue using the already rendered component.